# SELECT Statement within IF statement

Tags: if-statement, plsql, reportbuilder3.0

I would like to get a different result to my select statement when a parameter is 0, 1 or 2. I am not very skilled in PLSQL so I am not sure if my code would give the expected result. If i run this code i get a "SQL statement ignored" on line 3.

```
BEGIN
IF (:PARTYPE = 1) THEN
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE to_date(date) >= (Select to_date(sysdate)from DNV.dual)
ELSE
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE to_date(date) <= (Select to_date(sysdate)from DNV.dual)
END IF;
END;
```

This is just a example of my SELECT statement. Later this statement will become longer and more complex but I think this shows which results I am trying to get.

Below is a copy of my entire code but because I am not allowed to show this it has become very unreadable:

```
BEGIN
IF (:PARTYPE = 1) THEN    
Select table1.Column1
         , table1.Column2
         , table1.Column3
         , table1.Column4
         , table1.Column5
         , table1.Column6
         , table1.Column7
         , table1.Column8
         , table1.Column9
         , table1.Column10
         , table1.Column11
         , table1.Column12
         , (Select table2.ColumnX From x2 table2 Where somthing) as "something"      From x1 table1
        WHERE to_date(date) >= (Select to_date(sysdate)from DNV.dual)
      Order by columnX
ELSE    
Select table1.Column1
         , table1.Column2
         , table1.Column3
         , table1.Column4
         , table1.Column5
         , table1.Column6
         , table1.Column7
         , table1.Column8
         , table1.Column9
         , table1.Column10
         , table1.Column11
         , table1.Column12
         , (Select table2.ColumnX From x2 table2 Where somthing) as "something"      From x1 table1
        WHERE to_date(date) <= (Select to_date(sysdate)from DNV.dual)
      Order by columnX
END IF;
END;
```

I have created some new code with which i am trying to learn how a case statement works. This might help me with the code above. Unfortunately this code also doesn't work but I think it explanes my situation better. In this excample i use a separate table with data i made up. In some cases user2 is null but user1 is always filled. I want to get all items where user2 equals the parameter but if user2 is null and user1 does equal the paramter i still need that item to apear.

```
Select  t1.user1,
        t1.user2
        From table t1
        Where (Case
            When t1.user2 IS NULL Then t1.user1 in (:PARUSER)
            ELSE t1.user2 in (:PARUSER)
        End Case)
```

Comment: Try to replace `*` in the data you want. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Please show us your complete stored procedure.

Comment: I have added a censored version of my whole sql. I am using Microsoft SQL Report Builder. It is just a query used for filling a table.

Comment: That is not a stored procedure. If you want to return a result from PL/SQL code, you need to create a function that is then used like a table: `select * from some_function()` - you can't return a result from a PL/SQL block like that.

Comment: Is it posible to surround the WHERE statement with a if statement so only the where statement will change depending on a parameter. Or does that also require a function?

Comment: `DNV.dual` ???  You have a non-standard DUAL table?  That's bad.

Comment: Anyway, you say you want to execute *different statements* in the IF ...ELSE branches but your examples show *identical statements*.  Please edit your question and give us examples which actually demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.  Until we understand what you want it's unlikely we can help you.

Comment: my work delivered the database with tables they decided on the DNV.dual situation. The first select statement only selects the items with the date after the system date and the second statement only shows items with the date before the system date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the relational operator of the where clause depends on the partype, you cannot do the traditional CASE statement charm here. I'll have to resort with this one:

```
  SELECT * FROM x
    WHERE (to_date(date) >= (Select to_date(sysdate)from DNV.dual) AND :PARTYPE = 1)
       OR (to_date(date) <= (Select to_date(sysdate)from DNV.dual) AND :PARTYPE != 1)
```